# Can't create dialog using memory template - means what?

Tags: windows-7, wxwidgets

Getting following error message on closing my application.

Can't create dialog using memory template.

Note: Message dialogs are not appearing some times in my application, Is it related to this issue?.

Stuck without any ideas to proceed. kindly help.

Comment: Please put the text of the error message in your question and don't link out to images of it.

Comment: and maybe..source code?

Comment: thanks for your replies. I just wanted to understand the error message. Any info on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tips for finding the source of error messages in the future:

1. Grep the sources of the libraries you use (wxWidgets in this case) for the error message.
2. Or run the program under the debugger and break into it when the error is shown.

In this case, the first approach shows that the message happens during `wxDialog` creation if the Win32 function `CreateDialogIndirect()` fails. The error message is pretty bad because it doesn't provide much information, but OTOH it's hard to know what to say in it because this function is really, really not supposed to fail. Maybe the `GetLastError()` value, which should have been included in the error message that you don't show, provides some information, but without it I can only hypothesize that it's due to running out of memory or resources -- which would mean that there is an enormous leak of either the former or the latter in your application.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. The error message popup on closing the application and not shown at the time of issue.